# Problem writing an app that can startup after reboot

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reboot

I am trying to auto start an app after rebooting the phone. After looking into a few tutorials, none of the codes starts the app after rebooting the phone, and I have tested if `StartActivityOnBootReceiver.java` have received the action. This is my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HelloWorld">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".StartActivityOnBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

StartActivityOnBoostReceiver.java

```
public class StartActivityOnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Log.d("Receiver", "Received");
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I thought it is due to StartActivityOnBootReceiver haven't gotten the action of `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, so I added `Log.d("Receiver", "Received");`

And this is the result of the logcat
[image]

So, `StartActivityOnBootReceiver` have received the action, but it didn't turn on the app. Is there something I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest version of androids, I think this is not possible, unless you have root access or maybe even mark your app as a necessary service (some default apps are marked so by the company), i don't think it's possible normally

Comment: After downgrading the android system, I can boot the app on restart now!!! Thanks